# What is the measure of the $\measuredangle IAO$ angle in the triangle below?

Tags: geometry

For reference:In a triangle ABD, $\measuredangle B=124^\circ$, an external bisector is parallel to one of the sides of the triangle. Calculate $\measuredangle IAO$  whether "I" and "O" are incenter and orthocenter of ABC.

My progress:
I made the drawing and marked the relationships I found

[image]

Comment: It should be $14°+34°$, from your figure. What's wrong?

Comment: Is the tringle isosscel?

Comment: @Vasile, it has to be. We can easily prove that.

Comment: @Vasile..The statement says nothing about the triangle class

Comment: @Intelligentipauca...what should be $14^o+34^o$?

Comment: Triangle $ABC$ is isosceles: compare its angles with the two halves of the exterior angle. (BTW: your figure has $D$ in the place of $C$).

Comment: @Intelligentipauca ..Why is ABC isosceles? It could be 124,24 and 32...etc any other combination..

Comment: @ACB..Why is ABC isosceles? It could be 124,24 and 32...etc any other combination..

Comment: Hint: $BG\parallel AD$

Comment: https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/if-the-bisector-of-the-exterior-vertical-angle-of-a-triangle-be-parallel-to-the/

Comment: @Intelligentipauca..great demonstration...very useful

Comment: @ACB..With the tip of the angle being isosceles the problem becomes trivial...thanks for the help...

Comment: +1 for \measuredangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the hint of the "ABC" and Intelligentipauca:

$\triangle ABC(isósceles):\measuredangle DAB = 28^o=\measuredangle DCB\\
\text{Extend AB até K em AC}\\
AK \perp AC\\
\measuredangle BCK = 124^o - 90^o = 34^o \\
\therefore \measuredangle D=\measuredangle A = 62^o\\
AI (bissetriz) \therefore \measuredangle DIA =\frac{28^o}{2} = 14^o \implies\\
\boxed{\color{red}\measuredangle BAO = 62^o -14^o = 48^o}$

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate the hint of "ABC"?

Comment: The hint that the triangle is isosceles and the Intelligentipauca  posted the demo link